# How do I fix the automatic weight problem Ive tried everything I can think of

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

I have normals corrected, getting rid of unnecessary vertices. Im trying to rig this mesh and neither of these methods are working. I just want to know whats wrong with my mesh

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aD8y2sK8-ZztN7K_7bTUqKOVECcxaxIw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome Devin (.) Which methods you've tried already (?) What rig your are talking about (?) How should we get what's wrong without seeing anything (?) add an image or better a blend (.) and please put **some effort** into your question (.)

Comment: sorry, new to stackexchange.

Comment: I have tried to use a single bone to limit the number of variables. That didn't work either